# Alter SPHINCS+ to have collision probability=0 and remove entropy source when signing

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, hash-signature

If you alter the SPHINCS+ signature scheme such that the number of signatures it can sign is the same as the number of hashes the hashing algorithm can output such that for example if you have a 2^256 hash SPHINCS+ would be altered to be able to sign 2^256 messages.

Would you then be able to remove any requirement for an entropy source when signing? And render the probability of a hash signature collision at precisely 0? By having the message hash uniquely determine the path from the root through all the subtrees to the leaf.

And how big would the signatures be?

Answer (score 2):

> If you alter the SPHINCS+ signature scheme such that the number of signatures it can sign is the same as the number of hashes the hashing algorithm can output such that for example if you have a 2^256 hash SPHINCS+ would be altered to be able to sign 2^256 messages.

Easy enough - the number of messages you can sign really is a function of the hypertree height and the size/numbers of FORS trees - the size of the hashing algorithm doesn't actually come into play (and so there's no reason they couldn't happen to be the same size)

> Would you then be able to remove any requirement for an entropy source when signing?

There's no *requirement* now; Sphincs+ allows you to not provide a randomizer; if you don't, it's completely deterministic ("look ma, no entropy")

> And render the probability of a hash signature collision at precisely 0?

Obviously not - Sphincs+ can sign messages longer than a Sphincs+ signature, and so if we view the signing process as a mapping between messages and signatures, that process must have collisions.

> And how big would the signatures be?

Actually, with Sphincs+ there's a bunch of trade-offs between signature size and signature generation time (and some other things as well); the hash length obviously factors in as well, and so we can't give a hard and fast rule.  On the other hand, one superficial but not wildly inaccurate analysis is to note that the hypertree depth is roughly the log of the number of signatures you can generate (for current Sphincs+ parameter sets, that log is 64, and so the current parameter sets have hypertree heights approximately 64) - if you extend the number of signatures to $2^{256}$, you get a hypertree height of about 256.  And, if you keep the signature generation time not significantly slower, you need toe keep each Merkle tree height about the same, and so you need about 4 times as many layers (and so have about 4 times as many WOTS+ signatures).  The WOTS+ signatures take up much of the room; since the FORS authentication paths won't change drastically, you'll looking at a signature size not quite 4 times as large as the current Sphincs+ signatures.

Comment: To clarify, regarding collisions, any collision would have to happen with the hash itself and not SPHINCS+, correct? And would that fulfill the 'requirement' that no two hashes collide within a leaf (past the allowable number of collisions due to FORS) such that the danger of a leak in 2^256 SPHINCS+ with a 2^256 hash is 0? What I was asking if it's possible to guarantee that every single hash in the 2^256 hashset gets its own unique leaf.

Comment: "any collision would have to happen with the hash itself and not SPHINCS+, correct?"; no, that's not correct - you can get Sphincs+ signature collisions from collisions in hashes in the Sphincs+ structure itself - you might need multiple such collisions, but the probability of that happening is certainly not 0.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. What I'm trying to ascertain if its possible to alter SPHINCS+ such that any and all collisions would be entirely due to the hash primitive and not from the SPHINCS+ construction. If there are internal collisions within SPHINCS+ that would be because of hash collisions. I'm looking for a guarantee that SPHINCS+ will not under any circumstances be directly responsible for signing multiple different messages with the same leaf too many times due to the limitation of how many signatures it can sign vs. potential maximum hash set size.

Comment: @LeanneK.: if you are looking for a way to avoid signature collisions, the obvious way would be to include the initial hash in the signature.  However, if you're looking for a guarantee not to reuse a leaf more than N times, well, you'd need something stateful (which Sphincs+ tries to avoid)

Comment: "However, if you're looking for a guarantee not to reuse a leaf more than N times, well, you'd need something stateful (which Sphincs+ tries to avoid)" This is indeed what I'm looking for but without being stateful. Why is it not possible to have the message to be signed (which is just the hash of the message) entirely determine the path from the root to the leaf in a unique way such that no other hash can lead to the same leaf? This was part of the original question. There could still be hash collisions causing complications but that would no longer be SHPCINCS+ causing the danger.